Usar 2 DefaultRequestHeaders en request http
Hola estoy haciendo una llamada a una api pero necesito 2 headers, este es mi codigo, estoy obteniendo un Forbidden como respuesta pero no estoy seguro si es por mi codigo.
El error que obtengo es

[Main Exception Message] --> One or more errors occurred. (Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.) [Inner Exception Message] -->Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

  private async Task<string> Invoke(string action, bool isLoginCall, bool IsPostAction, JObject data = null)
    {
        string result = "";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL + (!isLoginCall ? "my-api/" : ""));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            if (!isLoginCall)
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("User-Agent", "my-service");

            var requestUri = new Uri(action, UriKind.Relative);
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            if (IsPostAction)
                response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            else
                response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (!_successResponseCodes.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode)))
            {
                JObject obj = new JObject();
                obj["StatusCode"] = Convert.ToString(response.StatusCode);
                obj["RequestURI"] = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri;
                if (response.Content.Headers.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JObject respObject = JObject.Parse(responseMessage);
                    obj["Message"] = respObject["responseMsg"];
                }
                else
                    obj["Message"] = null;

                throw new Exception(obj.ToString());
            }

            if (!isLoginCall)
                result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            else
                result = (response.Headers.GetValues("Authorization") as string[])?[0];
        }

        return await Task.Run(() => result);
    }


EL mensaje lo dice, Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <
1 .revisa que en tu respuesta no tenga caracteres ilegales como el mayor que o menor que. tienes mas información sobre lo que te retorna antes de que serializes el objeto, es decir la respuesta en crudo?
2 .otra teoría es que en tu heder tengas caracteres ilegales, revisa que en _token no tenga esos caracteres

Hola que tal, el problema que tengo es mas bien como agregar los dos headers, quiero saber si como los puse esta bien
